# ical with php without needing to put timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have created ical file from php and it works fine. but when I import into the google calendar, it changes the time.

after doing research, it's timezone issue. so I tried fixing it by removing Z (UTC) from the time, but time is still wrong after import.

is there a way that if I set following event time, it should work fine for all the import, regardless on which timezone they have set for there calendar.

```
        $ical ="BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n".
                "VERSION:2.0\n".
                "PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN\n";

        $start  = strtotime('2013-7-26 2:36 am');
        $end    = (60*1); // end in one minute

         $ical .="BEGIN:VEVENT\n".
                        "UID:" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . "@".site::$domain_only."\n".
                        "DTSTAMP:" . date('Ymd\THis'). "\n".
                        "DTSTART:" . date('Ymd\THis', $start)."\n".
                        "DTEND:" . date('Ymd\THis', $start+$end)."\n".
                        "SUMMARY: My Event\n".
                        "END:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way in iCalendar to do this, is by using what they call 'floating time' it does exactly what you want, and you indeed only have to remove the Z from the times.

If this does not work with google calendar, then it means they do not support floating times and the unfortunate answer would then be 'this is not possible'.

Comment: Looking at this old Google groups thread Google Calendar still probably doesn't support floating times http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/Xjxs5UjhsXI @Evert thanks for this is interesting to know!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the time zone of the calendar with one line

```
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to set events without timezone support. if you import our calendar into london timezone. it should still show event on 2:00 am and if the event was imported into New York timezone, then time should still be 2:00 am. how can i accomplish that?